# Sending table from Server to Client via [OperationContract]

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, networking

I have some problem. I have a simple chat on WCF tech. Chat program consists of server part and client part. I need to pack a table from database and send it to client. But I have no clue how to do that properly, so I decide to do this, and of course, I have a problem: client doesn't recieve the table. What could it be?

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ChattingInterfaces ///chatting interface
    {
        [ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IClient))]
        public interface IChattingService
        { 
            [OperationContract]
            List<ITableContent> content();
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using ChattingInterfaces;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace ChattingServer /// server part of program
{
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class ChattingService : IChattingService
    {
        public List<ITableContent> content()
        {
            List<ITableContent> result = new List<ITableContent>();
            result.Add(new TableContent()); /// packing table to client
            return result;
        }

    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ChattingInterfaces
{
    public interface ITableContent
    {
        List<string> nick { get; set; }
        List<bool> status { get; set; }
        List<decimal> id { get; set; }
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using ChattingInterfaces;
using DataContext1;
using Devart.Data.Oracle;
using System.Data;

namespace ChattingServer
{
    public class TableContent:ITableContent
    {
        ABDDataContext db;
        List<object> rList;

        List<string> ITableContent.nick
        {
            get
            {
                return db.TABLEs.AsParallel().Select(f => f.NICK).ToList();
            }
            set
            {  
            }
        }

        List<bool> ITableContent.status
        {
            get
            {
                return db.TABLEs.AsParallel().Select(f => f.STATUS).ToList();
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }

        List<decimal> ITableContent.id
        {
            get
            {
                return db.TABLEs.AsParallel().Select(f => f.ID).ToList();
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ChattingInterfaces;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ChattingClient
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static IChattingService Server;
        private static DuplexChannelFactory<IChattingService> _channelFactory;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IChattingService>(new ClientCallBack(this),"ChattingServiceEndPoint");
    Server = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    var p = Server.content(); /// CommunicationException was unhandled!
}

////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: try to use signalr.Its an easy way to create a chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have issues with knowntypes, sending Interfaces in WCF is very problematic - as you need to create knowntype resolver. and for chatting app to use WCF is like hitting a nail with 1 ton bomb. Why not to use WebAPI server either selfhosted or not, and use signalr client?

anyway your tablecontent dont have datacontract attribute - WCF dont know what to serial

Comment: I need WCF because chat is just a part of whole system. If you could show me the right way of sending tables (there is the only goal) I'll be very VERY appreciate.

Comment: have a look in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/738844/Using-WCF-Data-Contract-Known-Types-by-Example